# How do you flag cells by comparing values in another column with the same 'ID' column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365, xlookup, index-match

I have a sample table like this:

base

[image: 1]

I wanted to flag if there is an increase in Output of the same ID compared to the previous Date.
Note that the data is **only sorted by Date**.

*Expected output:*
output

[image: 2]

I've been trying to find the correct formula so that it only *compares between current output with previous output of the same ID in previous date* with INDEX-MATCH functions and had no luck.
Thank you for your assistance.

```
=IF(AND(D2>INDEX($D$2:$D$9, MATCH(C2,$C$2:$C$9,0)-1), C2=INDEX($C$2:$C$9, MATCH(B2,$B$2:$B$9,0)-1)), "Flag", "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=IF(C2>TAKE(TAKE(FILTER($C$2:$C2,$B$2:$B2=B2,0),-2),1),"Flag","")
```

[image]

Comment: That looked great. 
Could you please elaborate the logic behind that expression?
I'm trying to find a workaround without using dynamic array functions like TAKE and FILTER. 

thankyou for your assistance nonetheless.

Comment: `FILTER()` function will filter output based on `ID`. First `TAKE` function with parameter `-2` will keep last 2 output. Then `TAKE` with 1 will keep second last output to compare with current output (all are based on ID). IF function will detect either it increase or not.

Comment: If you want to avoid dynamic formulas then could search for `AGGREGATE()` function.

Comment: Thanks for keeping it simple, I'll check on AGGREGATE() function soon.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an array approach. In cell `D2` use the following formula:

```
=LET(A, A2:A9, B, B2:B9, C, C2:C9, MAP(A, B,C, LAMBDA(aa,bb,cc, LET(
  f, FILTER(C, (B=bb) * (A < aa),""), IF(OR(@f="", TAKE(f,-1)>=cc),"", "Flag")))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

On each `MAP` iteration we filter **Output** column (`C`) by **ID** (`B`) equals to `bb` and only previous dates. To select filtered the output (`f`) that corresponds to previous date we use: `TAKE(f,-1)`, i.e. select the last filtered row (data is sorted by date in ascending order). Then we check for empty condition: the filter result is empty (`@f=""`), i.e. no result returned under filter condition or the output is not ascending.